# Logarithmic Spiral

Tags: calculus, geometry, analytic-geometry

Let's assume a particle starts on an equilateral triangle of side length "A" with some constant speed u. The particle goes on a logarithmic spiral around the centroid. Find the distance covered by the particle when it completes the first circle.

I am a High school student and while solving a physics question, I thought about it, after searching on the net, I found out that its actually a logarithmic spiral, but couldn't find the right method to derive the distance traveled. I think it could be solved using integration but am not able to apply that to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In polar coordinates, [the logarithmic spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_spiral) is described by $r=r_0e^{a\theta}$.

The arc length $ds$ in polar coordinates is given by $$ds=\sqrt{r^2+\left(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\right)^2}d\theta=r_0e^{a\theta}\sqrt{1+a^2}d\theta$$

The length of the path is $$\int_0^{2\pi}ds=r_0\sqrt{1+a^2}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{a\theta}d\theta=r_0\sqrt{1+a^2}\frac{e^{2\pi a}-1}{a}$$